# how to solve : E/Volley: [230] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.43.83/test.php

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Request request = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                "http://192.168.43.83/test.php",
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.i("Get_Response: ", response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("Get_Error: ", error.toString());
            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(8000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

**Log Response "Get_Error: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError"**

I've changed "require local" to "require all granted" in "httpd-vhosts.conf"file but nothing happened

Comment: Do you have any headers which you need to pass?

Comment: are you able to access this url from your device's web browser?

Comment: yes It is access n my browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its forbidden error .look and log what do you exactly send as a request . check the url correctness . ّI had the same problem when set some field in url with another language the same might happen to you .